# Refused to display in a frame

Tags: iframe, content-security-policy

I am using an iframe to show a calendar on it. But I keep getting the following;

> Refused to display 'https://cal.mixmax.com/user1' in a frame because
>   an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "frame-ancestors 'self' https://mail.google.com
>   https://inbox.google.com https://*.force.com https://*.mixmax.com".

I tried to have the meta for Content-Security-Policy as the following but no luck.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="frame-ancestors 'self' 
      https://mail.google.com 
      https://inbox.google.com 
      https://*.force.com 
      https://*.mixmax.com">
```

Any idea how to overcome it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not a misconfiguration on your side, it's on the CSP directive on Mixmax side. They have the following directive on their page:

```
content-security-policy:
  frame-ancestors 'self'
  https://mail.google.com
  https://inbox.google.com
  https://*.force.com
  https://*.mixmax.com;;
frame-src:
  https://*.stripe.com
  https://*.facebook.com
  https://*.mixmax.com;;
```

So you cannot frame it, unless you are from any of the listed domains.

One way to overcome that is to create a proxy on your site, access MixMax on the behalf of the client, and send the data to your frame, as CSP is client-enforced only.